# How can I make my phone require a password to open Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, privacy, application-locker

I want my phone to require a password to enter the Google Play app, so if I let someone else, such as a friend, use my phone they can't go into the app and snoop around.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 8.0.

Comment: It is best if you setup a guest user account for complete isolation from your apps and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock).

On its Play Store page, it is stated that:

> AppLock can lock Facebook, Whatsapp, Gallery, Messenger, Snapchat, Instagram, SMS, Contacts, Gmail, Settings, incoming calls and any app you choose. Prevent unauthorized access and guard privacy. Ensure security.

Below are the steps to configure the app:

1. Install the app. After the installation is completed, open it.
2. You will be prompted to create a pattern that will be used to unlock the app (I advise you use a different pattern than the one used to unlock your phone).

   [image: IMG:]
3. The next windows will ask to enter an email address for security purpose.

   [image: IMG:]
4. Next, a dialog box will appear asking to grant the app usage access. Click permit, then on the list select APPLock and switch on usage access permission.

   [image: IMG:]
5. Go back to the app, click on the Play Store. It will now be locked.

   [image: IMG:]
6. When you or anyone else try to open the Play Store, he/she be prompted to enter the pattern you created.

   [image: IMG:]

**Disclaimer:** I have no relation with those who develop the app.

Comment: +1 [Maxlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.Maxr1998.xposed.maxlock) is another good alternative, free software, works with and without root with automation features too. Most importantly, it hides the content of recent view of locked apps to ensure content is hidden from prying eyes

Answer (score 0):

Mostly samsung devices have app lock by default if your device doesn't have just downlaod an app lock from play store and set it up and lock the app you wanna lock

Comment: It would terribly help if you could mention where this inbuilt app locker can be located in at least Galaxy S9 (if not the most Samsung devices as you said).

Comment: I searched everything and couldn't find it but I figured it out!!!

Comment: @NonaBinder can you tell us what you figured out? This could help future askers as well.

Comment: I followed the instructions for the  applock and now I have to put a password in to get into it!!!!! It worked perfectly!!!!